# I made a function and for some reason it is not being called. I was able to deploy it

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Hi everyone I am new to firebase. I made a function and for some reason it is not being called. I was able to deploy it. what I am trying to do is that every time I change a value my slack will get notified but when I add a value/document nothing happens. I have looked in the functions and they have not been called at all.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var request = require("request");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.notifyNewRecord = functions.firestore
    .document('stallion/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const newValue = snap.data();
      const name = newValue.name;
      const points = newValue.points;

    return request.post(
      "https://hooks.slack.com/I have my slack id here in the code",
      {json:{text: `<${user} received ${points} point for an excepted answer>.`}}
    )
```

This is the structure of my database the database and then stallion documents and the record is right on the document name: xxxx, points: xxxx. I am using the free tier for firestore don't know if it matters. I see the function in my database functions any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see anything in the log?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec So for some reason I am now seeing stuff in the log but before I wasn't I had a problem that user wasn't defined I defined name see above also some other error with slack.

Comment: I don't think you can make outboud requests on the free tier of firebase

Comment: @NicholasPesa yes I had to update my plan I got a message that I needed to update it before I wasn't even getting that message

Comment: Ok so outside of the plan upgrade, I think you may want to finish the POST request you are making instead of returning it. So you might wait for that request to finish and then however that HTTP request is resolved (success or error), then return that as the status of the request.

Comment: @NicholasPesa thanks this is just for testing the functionality and show a proof of concept to the business I hear you though I up voted you though

Comment: @AaronRabinowitz appreciate the votes! Hope this could be of help and works out for you! You are definitely on the right track here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fire-base functions tab takes a while to upload if the function has been called. Also you cannot make calls in the free tier as mentioned by Nicholas Pesa. There is at least one mistake in the above code that user inside the call is undefined it should be name.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an onCreate trigger, which only fires when a new document in created in the "stallion" collection.  It won't trigger for changes to existing documents.  For that, you would need to use an onUpdate on onWrite trigger.  Please be sure to read the [documentation for Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) to better understand how they work.

Comment: I will give you this answer if you can tell me how to check if a doc has been created that is what I am trying to do